# kriegaex/jgrapht: No Hamiltonian cycle (HC) found

Tags: jgrapht

I am not found place open issue in github https://github.com/kriegaex/jgrapht
I test code

```java
Graph<String, DefaultEdge> graph = GraphTypeBuilder
  .<String, DefaultEdge>directed()
  .allowingMultipleEdges(false)
  .allowingSelfLoops(false)
  .edgeClass(DefaultEdge.class)
  .buildGraph();

graph.addVertex("a");
graph.addVertex("b");
graph.addVertex("c");
graph.addVertex("d");
graph.addEdge("a", "b");
graph.addEdge("b", "c");
graph.addEdge("c", "a");
graph.addEdge("c", "d");
graph.addEdge("d", "b");

new CyclicTransitiveReduction<>(graph).reduce();
```

it give me an runtime exception (line breaks added)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
  No Hamiltonian cycle (HC) found.
  This should never happen and indicates an error in the algorithm,
  because the graph is strongly connected and a HC must therefore exist.
```

don't raise exception

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a place to report bugs. Also your directed graph does not contain a HC. Finally you are referring to code outside of the official jgrapht package. The code you are referring to is a fork created by someone who is not affiliated with jgrapht

Comment: @JorisKinable, correct, I am not affiliated, but this code is from my PR, which has not been accepted for purely nitpicky, pseudo-philisophical reasons. There were no objections whatsoever against the functionality as such or the test coverage. It was about code style and someone trying to coerce me into moving classes to other packages, even though I placed mine exactly where the related classes are. I refused to do this refactoring on top of the minimally invasive PR, precisely because I am not affiliated with the project. A committer should take care of that. Hence, the PR was left open.

Comment: For reference: Three weeks ago, I fixed the bug in [this commit](https://github.com/kriegaex/jgrapht/commit/d4e64e526a362e867d2a3b9b817349a4c1a5a0ee) and also rebased the old PR on the latest main branch.